# How can I specify the amount of spaces between columns by using tabulate module in python

Tags: python, tabulate

Id like to know if there is some argument I can pass to tabulate module and specify the quantity of empty spaces between columns.

I can see there are 2 spaces by default but I didnt find how do manipulate that. This is script example.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

data = [
  ["Name","LastName", "Age"],
  ["Juan","Lopez", "22"],
  ["Luisa","Perez", "24"],
  ["Ana","Sanchez", "23"]
]

print (tabulate(data, stralign="right", tablefmt="plain"))
```

Output:

```
 Name  LastName  Age
 Juan     Lopez   22
Luisa     Perez   24
  Ana   Sanchez   23
```

The complete task is about extract data from a plan text and organize it. One way I did to solve the problem was adding empty columns between each data column but maybe is not the most eficcient way.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) doesn't seem to have an argument for this. Maybe look into [prettytable](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/), and especially the "Changing the appearance of your table - the hard way" chapter, that allows you to be more flexible with the table style.

EDIT: [texttable](https://pypi.org/project/texttable/) may be useful too, as you can define the column width. The documentation seems to be a bit lacking though, and while the ease of use may be better, the modularity seems to be a bit worse at first glance.

Comment: Thank you @GregoirePelegrin I look at prettytable and seems to be really flexible, I tested several ways to do what I want )

Comment: Do not hesitate to post it as an answer later, for the ones in the future who will encounter the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reduce the column separator width to a single character with:

```py
tablefmt = "minpadding"
tabulate._table_formats[tablefmt] = tabulate.TableFormat(
  lineabove=tabulate.Line("", "-", " ", ""),
  linebelowheader=tabulate.Line("", "-", " ", ""),
  linebetweenrows=None,
  linebelow=tabulate.Line("", "-", " ", ""),
  headerrow=tabulate.DataRow("", " ", ""),
  datarow=tabulate.DataRow("", " ", ""),
  padding=0,
  with_header_hide=["lineabove", "linebelow"],
)
tabulate.multiline_formats[tablefmt] = tablefmt
tabulate.tabulate_formats = list(sorted(tabulate._table_formats.keys()))
rows = [
    ["Cell 1", "Cell 2"],
    ["Cell 3", "Cell 4a\nCell 4b"],
    ["Cell 5", "Cell 6"],
]
print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, headers="firstrow", tablefmt=tablefmt))
```

which produces:

```
Cell 1   Cell 2
-------- --------
Cell 3   Cell 4a
         Cell 4b
Cell 5   Cell 6
```

Comment: That's great. Did you consider adding "minpadding" tablefmt upstream? I think would be great.

Answer (score -3):

I know this is an older post, but could you not use whitespace to extend the cell?

> Text formatting By default, tabulate removes leading and trailing
> whitespace from text columns. To disable whitespace removal, set the
> global module-level flag PRESERVE_WHITESPACE:
>
> import tabulate tabulate.PRESERVE_WHITESPACE = True

[Tabulate on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

Comment: Well the question isn't about trailing spaces but a solution to customize column width. So things are better left the way they are in unless you have an alternate solution. Welcome to SO

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34414799)